# Narrowing conversions in C++11: what is the "actual value after conversion"?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

Is the following code legal in C++11?

```
int16_t x {0xaabb};
int64_t xxxx {0xaaaabbbbccccdddd};
```

The code is from "The C++ Programming Language" 4th edition (page 150).

As we know, narrowing conversion is not allowed for list initialization, and among the standard's definition of narrowing conversion, we have:

> A narrowing conversion is an implicit conversion
>   —  [...]
>   — from an integer type or unscoped enumeration type to an integer type that cannot represent all the values of the original type, except where the source is a constant expression and the actual value after conversion will fit into the target type and will produce the original value when converted back to the original type.

Checking the rule of narrowing conversion against the sample code, I justify that the sample code is illegal because `0xaabb` and `0xaaaabbbbccccdddd` cannot be represented in `int16_t` and `int64_t` respectively.  Is that correct?

But I don't quite understand the wording "except where the source is a constant expression and **the actual value after conversion will fit into the target type** and will produce the original value when converted back to the original type".  I wonder in what scenario **the actual value after conversion** cannot **fit into the target type**.  Since conversions between integer types are always valid (though implementation-defined in the case where the destination type is signed and the source value cannot be represented in the destination type, but it's not undefined behaviour anyway), is it always true that "the value **after** conversion will fit into the target type"?  And from this point of view, I'm starting to question my judgement of the sample code being narrowing conversion.  If that is the case, why does the standard put something always true in a condition?  Why not just say "except where the source is a constant expression and the actual value after conversion will produce the original value when converted back to the original type"?

Can someone help me clarify this?  Thank you!

Comment: I think the question comes from the fact that `0xaabb` can be considered a "positive" constant, but when assigned to an `int16_t`, it becomes a negative number. Hmm, I just replied to a comment that's no longer here, but I'll leave this as it may clarify the question.

Comment: Can you improve the title so that it differentiates this question from others in a list of questions?

Comment: Empirically, it should be legal since GCC emits a warning (so the compiler is demonstrably aware of the issue) but it _does not_ emit an error. If it was truly illegal, the compile should break with an error (not a warning).

Comment: @Damon: your conclusion doesn't follow. The standard does not require that compilers cease compilation with an error in the face of illegal code. All that is required is that the error is diagnosed, and a warning does so. The purpose of `-pedantic-errors` on GCC is to promote such warnings to errors.

Comment: @Damon There is no such requirement in the standard, and it is by design that GCC (just like other compilers) accepts some things not valid in standard C++ with only a warning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a defect in the standard, see [CWG issue 1449](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1449). The text has been changed to

> from an integer type or unscoped enumeration type to an integer type that cannot represent all the values of the original type, except where the source is a constant expression whose value after integral promotions will fit into the target type

Note: the issue's status, DRWP, means that officially, the standard has not yet been changed, and an argument can be made that at least your `int64_t` example is legal in C++11. Compilers already implement the new rules, though, as this was already the intended meaning of the original wording.

Comment: Thank you very much for the information.  I'm still unclear about the difference between "`will fit into`" and "`can be represented in`".  If they mean the same thing, then the `int64_t` example should be narrowing conversion.  If they are not same, then what's the exact difference?

Comment: @goodbyeera Unless I'm misreading, they mean the same thing, so both the `int16_t` and `int64_t` examples would be a narrowing conversion based on the new wording.

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at how the value is converted to a signed integer:

> 4.7/3 If the destination type is signed, the value is unchanged if it can be represented in the destination type (and bit-field width); otherwise, **the value is implementation-defined**.

So these conversions give implementation-defined values. A sensible implementation will define the conversion to give the corresponding negative value for that bit-pattern, which does fit into the target type.

So the question is, does conversion back to the type of the literal preserve the value? This depends on the implementation-defined size of the literal types. The first will preserve the value if `int` has exactly 16 bits, but not if it's larger (in which case `0xaabb` will be signed, and the conversion will give a negative value). Likewise, the second will preserve the value if either `int` has exactly 64 bits, or `int` is smaller and `long long` has exactly 64 bits.

Conclusion: it depends. On a typical current platform with 32-bit `int` and 64-bit `long long`, the first will narrow while the second won't. GCC agrees, and issues a warning for the first with `-pedantic`.